# Zend Framework Hosting - cannot include bootstrap.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using a hosting solution for my Zend Framework app, but cannot get it to load the application/bootstrap.php file.

When I ftp on to the server, my doc root is /webspace/httpdocs/euro.millionsresults.com

I placed the application, public, library etc. dirs in this directory.

I then created a .htaccess, as per http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/

/webspace/httpdocs/euro.millionsresults.com/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

This rewrites everything to my index.php file, which then includes the public/index.php file of the ZF, which is correct and works fine. The index.php file is:

/webspace/httpdocs/euro.millionsresults.com/index.php

```
<?php
include 'public/index.php';
```

If I put in an echo in the public/index.php file, it works fine, proving public/index.php is now called when you try to access the site.

The problem is, the public/index.php file needs to include the ../application/bootstrap.php file:

/webspace/httpdocs/euro.millionsresults.com/public/index.php

```
<?php
echo "this is working";
require('../application/bootstrap.php');
```

However, **application/bootstrap.php does not get included.**

If I put a die at the very top of application/bootstrap.php, nothing gets rendered.

I have tried the following for public/index.php:

require('../../../application/bootstrap.php');
require('/webspace/httpdocs/euro.millionsresults.com/application/bootstrap.php');

But nothing works in including application/bootstrap.php.

Does anyone know what to do here? It is a cheap host I am on, with no access to php.ini.

**Additional Info**:

The issue seems to be with the include_path. When I do get_include_path(), I have:

```
:/php/includes:/usr/share/pear:/usr/libexec/php4-cgi/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear
```

**I can set_include_path(), but what do I set it to?**

I have tried:

```
set_include_path('/webspace/httpdocs/euro.millionsresults.com/application' . PATH_SEPARATOR. get_include_path());
set_include_path('/../../../application' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
set_include_path('../application' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

None of which work, i.e. when I have the following in my public/index.php file, I always get "does not exist":

```
<?php
echo "In file public/index.php <br>";

set_include_path('/../../../application' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

echo get_include_path();

if (file_exists('/../application/bootstrap.php')){
    echo "<br>exists";
}
else {
    echo "<br>does not exist";
}
```

It doesn't matter what file I check existence of - any file in the application folder, or any folder not in public, is not found.

Comment: what are the permissions of this folder? What user/group is its owner?

Comment: my zend framework .htaccess file is: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: My Zend .htaccess file is different too, the .htaccess I posted above is just to redirect everything to index.php in the doc root, which then calls the ZF public/index.php file.

Comment: Permissions are 755, and owner is the same owner as all other dirs.

Comment: I think ths .htaccess file is the cause of this issue. Also require should use realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'))

Comment: Its not htaccess, please see adjusted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `public/index.php` file, this line:

```
require('../application/bootstrap.php');
```

assumes that your *current working directory* is `public/` and that *relative to this dir*, one dir up, there is an `application/bootstrap.php` - relative `require` calls are relative to the current working directory or to the include_path. It seems that the ZF code assumes `public/` is the document root, which is not true in your case.

In Web environments, usually, the current working directory is the document root. So in your case, you may want to change `require('../application/bootstrap.php')` to:

```
require('application/bootstrap.php');
```

If that does not work, I suggest finding out what the current working directory is vs. the `public/index.php` directory by running something like:

```
var_dump(getcwd(), __DIR__);
```

(if your PHP version is outdated, replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`)

and, do your `require` call relative to that.

Comment: Aghh, that was it! Thanks